# Rank of a block of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ be an invertible matrix where $A_{11}$ is square. Let $A^{-1} =: B = \begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12} \\ B_{21} & B_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ and shape of $B_{11}$ is same as $A_{11}$.

What is known about the relationships between the ranks of $A_{21}$ and $B_{21}$? For example, if either $A_{11}$ or $A_{22}$ is invertible, then it can be easily shown using the block inverse formula that the ranks are equal. I presume when this is not true, the equality does not hold in general. Is this correct? In that case, what bounds are known?

Comment: If the diagonal blocks are not invertible, the other blocks should be of full rank, otherwise it is hard to see the whole matrix being invertible.  Do you know of counterexamples?  Gerhard "Full Rank Comes From Somewhere" Paseman, 2020.05.12.

Comment: Ah: Take some permutation matrices.  Perhaps this will suggest some conditions the ranks can satisfy.  Gerhard "I See Some Counterexamples Now" Paseman, 2020.05.12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That paper from Strang and Nguyen gives the answer: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036144503434381

See "theorem 2.1: (nullity theorem). Complementary submatrices of a square matrix and its inverse have the same nullity". In your case the complementary submatrices are exactly $A_{21}$ and $B_{21}$, so their ranks are equal.